# JMF in a web-application on Tomcat

Tags: java, jmf

I created a web application that is using Java Media Framework. It runs in my unit tests and successfully finds the capturing devices. However when I deploy my application to Tomcat the same method returns an empty list of Capturing devices as if Tomcat is missing something that helps JMF to find media devices.

I suspect jmf.jar cannot find native dll's of JMF package, which somehow are visible in Eclipse but are not visible when application is deployed to Tomcat.

Can anyone give a hint how to deploy jmf correctly?

As example: this application http://sourceforge.net/projects/webjmf/ claims that it is working, however when war file is deployed to my Tomcat it cannot find any capturing devices.

Comment: put your jmf.jar in tomcat lib folder and then check whether it works or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to copy all JMF dll files into /bin directory.
DLL files are native libraries that are used by jmf.jar to interact with Web Cam. So these libraries should be loaded by Tomcat.